# Call a method in C# determined by a parameter

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a list of methods I wish to call and a button accompaning each and a generic method to handle the buttons.

Using the commandArgument how can I run the selected method.

E.g. Click run method1 button.  In handler for button click call the method as named in commandArgument

Comment: You really should think about changing your program-pattern to use delegates for the methods - this is possible to misuse, especially when used with strings as arguments..

Comment: argh... set a tag for asp.net and revoked my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the string in the CommandArgument matches the name of a method? If you must do this then you could use reflection. I'm assuming you've basically got a single button click event for each button or you wouldn't be asking this:

```
private void MethodA() { }

protected void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string arg = ((Button)sender).CommandArgument;  // = MethodA
    MethodInfo method = this.GetType().GetMethod(arg);
    method.Invoke(this, null);
}
```

Although this looks like a massive code smell. Why do you have to do it this way? Why can you not just give each button a separate event handler and call each method directly?

Alternatively, why not use a switch statement on the argument:

```
protected void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string arg = ((Button)sender).CommandArgument;  // = MethodA
    switch (arg)
    {
        case "MethodA":
            MethodA(); break;
        case "MethodB":
            MethodB(); break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Ahh... thats slow and dangerous... better would be to use delegates instead.

Answer (score 3):

Why not actually use something like this command pattern?

```
public interface ICommand
{
   bool CanExecute(string command);
   void Execute();
}

public class MethodACommand : ICommand
{
    private MyForm form;
    public MethodACommand(MyForm form) {... }

    public bool CanExecute(string command) { return command.Equals("MethodA"); }
    public void Execute() { form.MethodA(); }
}

public class CommandHandler
{
    public CommandHandler(IEnumerable<ICommand> commandString) {...}
    public Execute(string command) 
    {
        foreach(var command in Commands)
        {
             if (command.CanExecute(commandString))
             {
                 command.Execute();
                 break;
             }
        }
    }
}

protected void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string arg = ((Button)sender).CommandArgument;  // = MethodA
    commandHandler.Execute(arg);
}
```

Comment: You might as well use the Button.Command event rather than the Button.Click event.  You'd get a CommandEventArgs parameter that contains both the CommandName and CommandArgument, so you wouldn't need to grab them off of the Button itself. (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.command.aspx)

Comment: You are right about using the command event, I was typing this quick and modified the button-click calling code from a previous answer

Answer (score 1):

If you know all the methods that are to be called and the number is not very large I would just use a switch statement to call them. Otherwise you have to use reflection, see e.g. http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/CallMethodNameInString.aspx for some examples.

Comment: I know but I wanted to allow for the list to grow.
I have temporarly just set it up using a switch case statement

Answer (score 1):

I like Ian's answer, but if you want something less complex, you could just set up a dictionary of delegates:

```
private IDictionary<string, Action> actions = new Dictionary<string, Action> {
    { "MethodA", MethodA },
    { "MethodB", MethodB }
};
```

then

```
protected void Button_Command( object sender, CommandEventArgs e )
{
    if( actions.ContainsKey( e.CommandArgument ) )
        actions[e.CommandArgument]();
    else
        throw new ArgumentException( "Cannot find action for key: "+ e.CommandArgument );
}
```

of course, could be modified to accept arguments if you know their type.  this assumes MethodA and MethodB have no arguments and return void.